# How to send different email while creating credit memo based on online/offline refund

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo, refund, store-credit

I am in situation where I need to send different email while creating credit memo.
There always remains two cases, online refund and offline refund.
So, while creating credit-memo, if I am refunding online, then I want to send an email having mentioned that it is online refunded.
On other case, If I am refunding offline, then I want to send an email having mentioned that it is offline refunded.

I do also need to take care for the time when I click on already created credit memo and then selects send email (which send email to customer for the already generated credit memo).

Is there a way to do so? If yes, please help me to get this done!